# Replace passwords in config files using Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, passwords

I have a variety of nodeJS packages with config files containing a combination of environment specific config variables but also sensitive information/secrets (passwords, api keys etc).

Is there some way either to put placeholders in the config file and have a jenkins plugins, swap them out for valid values? In particular I'd like to be able to use the Jenkins credential plugin for passwords information?

If not what is the best way to customize config files for each environment securely?

Comment: Use env vars? https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env and [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

Comment: Is placing passwords in environment variables safe? I wouldn't think so?

Comment: As long as you use `.env` files instead of putting the variable declaration in your code, you just have to make sure you don't commit those `.env` files... Have a read of the dotenv package readme

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your specific use case, you can use environment variables, or you can save the information as Jenkins secrets and reference them like so in your pipeline:

```
environment {
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('jenkins-aws-secret-key-id')
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('jenkins-aws-secret-access-key')
}
```

See more here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#secret-text

Comment: I guess I am making this harder than it needs to be. I was thinking environment variables wouldn't be safe. In my ignorance I assumed environment variables were global and one user could see all the system environment variables (and therefore the passwords would be exposed to every user on the system). I guess that's not the case though?

Comment: You can definitely have system-wide environment variables, although these are very different to what you are intending to do. The environment variable, depending on how you implement it in a Jenkinsfile is ephemeral and exists only during the stage or job run.